# Invoke-WebRequest – Authentication fails (401) on Windows PowerShell but not on PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm trying to reach our Artifactory repository using the following PowerShell command:

```
$dest = 'https://artifactory.****.de/artifactory/*********/'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dest -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

While this works flawlessly in PowerShell 7.2.4, Windows PowerShell 5.1 throws an exception after I enter my credentials into the Enter Your Credential pop-up dialog:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : { "errors" : [ { "status" : 401, "message" : "Bad credentials" } ] }
In line:2 column:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dest -Credential (Get-Credential)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I suspect there may be an issue with my password, because it contains an umlaut character.

How can I make this work in Windows PowerShell 5.1?